# Laravel 5.6 ckfinder integration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ckfinder

I want to integrate ckfinder with my laravel but I am stuck with authentication.

I found many ways but there were for older laravel versions and none are working for 5.6.

I found this:

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once '../../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```

But I am getting Invalid request from Ckfinder when I put it in config.php

I would like to access Auth::check() and return it in authentication

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$request->setMethod('GET');

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle($request);

$config['authentication'] = function () {
    return auth()->check();
};
```

**EDIT**

So I had a look at index.php and copied this into config.php:

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

But I am getting runtime exceptions for $acl argument.

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Controller
>   "CKSource\CKFinder\Command\Init::execute()" requires that you provide
>   a value for the "$acl" argument. Either the argument is nullable and
>   no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or
>   because there is a non optional argument after this one. in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php:78
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(141):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver->getArguments(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>   Array) #1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(66):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request),
>   1) #2
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/public/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/CKFinder.php(610):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel- in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-dealer/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php
>   on line 78

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I spent some time with this and came up with this solution:

This function gets the value of `$_COOKIE['allowCkfinder']` and decrypts it using cipher and your app key.

```
// /public/ckfinder/config.php

$config['authentication'] = function () {
    $APP_KEY = "YOUR_APP_KEY";
    $cookie_contents = json_decode( base64_decode( $_COOKIE['allowCkfinder'], true ));
    $value = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->value );
    $iv = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->iv );

    return unserialize( openssl_decrypt($value, "AES-256-CBC", base64_decode($APP_KEY), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
};
```

When logging in user / admin set cookie with name allowCkfinder:
Also dont forget to remove the cookie on user logout.

```
// /app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php
if (Auth::attempt(['user_email' => $validatedData['email'], 'password' => $validatedData['password'], "user_active" => 1, "user_banned" => 0]))
{
    if (Auth::user()->user_admin == TRUE)
        return redirect()->intended('/')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('allowCkfinder', "1"));
    else
        return redirect()->intended('/');
}   else
{
    $request->session()->flash('error', __("E-mail and/or password do not match"));
    return redirect('login')->withInput();
}
```

That's the best I came up with.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how the authentication section looks like on one of my projects

```
/*============================ Enable PHP Connector HERE ==============================*/
// http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_authentication 

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$request->setMethod('GET');

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle($request);

$config['authentication'] = function () {
    return auth()->check();
};
```

Comment: I get this error: RuntimeException
Controller "CKSource\CKFinder\Command\Init::execute()" requires that you provide a value for the "$acl" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

Comment: Have you changed anything else on your ckfinder installation or in the config file? I feel this shouldn't be caused by the authentication code. Can you try using a fresh install of ckfinder and just paste in the auth code for starters?

Comment: now I get uknown error from ckfinder. Well I jsut copied / paste your code. Check updated question

Comment: When I dump this: var_dump(auth()->check()); it says true so I am confused, maybe I need to exclude ckfinder from htaccess rewrites?

Comment: but in ckfinder errors it says again the same about the $acl

Comment: you get a conflict with ckfinder Symfony  and laravel Symfony thats why you get acl